# Windows 10 Random Crashes During Usage/Repair/Reset (Not Enough Time), Safe Mode+Ordinary--need any fix?

Tags: windows-10, crash, bootable-media

**Detailing the problem:**

Computer randomly crashes due to fatal errors, mainly various `.dll` and `.sys` fails, but also kernel check failures, unexpected fault pages, and at times no error messages at all (text just ends above where the error should state). Though crash is inevitable, usage accelerates it (such as navigating through folders).

**Tried solutions:**

- Installing third party Windows repairs from internet, fail (not enough time prior crash).
- Using AOEMI Partition Handler to either create bootable drive/install Windows 8.1, fail (not enough time).
- Repairing (chkdsk, sfc, dism), fail (not enough time prior crash).
- Reset, partially and full, fail (not enough time prior crash).
- Running Windows 8.1 installer within Windows 10, fail (not compatible).
- Trying to make a bootable drive with Windows 8.1 to install, fail (not enough time).

One interesting issue is that twice I managed, with dism cmd commands, apply the iso image of Windows 8.1 to the bootable drive prior crash, but it got stuck at 20% while cmd acter as if it had completed the process (able to give cmd new commands).

Trying all above while running from boot menu/safe mode, fail. The crashes occur there too.

So what I'm asking for is any idea on how to fix this? Other than using an other computer to do so. Is there a quickly installed and quickly used program that could make a bootable/runable drive of an Windows 8.1 ISO? Or any magic fix I've not found yet?

**Edit1:**
Adding in stuff I've tried that also failed.

Comment: Make a bootable USB Key from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.  Start your computer with this key and then run Setup from the key. See if you can launch the Windows 10 Repair Install

Answer (score 0):

It could be hardware failure, e.g. a failing HDD or power supply.

Make a Live USB (on another machine), i.e. one that contains the whole operating system (OS) and does not need to be installed on the HDD, such as [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview). This is far easier than trying to find an old Windows-To-Go ISO and making it run from USB... It should take no more than a half hour to make the Live USB, and ten minutes or less to boot it. If a Live USB runs *flawlessly*, then you've narrowed down the problem to either the HDD or Windows OS. If the Live USB *also crashes* after a few minutes, it's other hardware issue, e.g. bad power supply, bad RAM or loose connector.